# problem overfitting model VGG16 small dataset

Tags: python-3.x

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFrxF.jpg)

i have two classes, each of them contains an equal number of pictures

Train

- 360 train pictures for classe one
- 360 train pictures for classe two

Test

- 90 test pictures classe one
- 90 test pictures classe two

my code

```
def load_split(basePath, csvPath):
    data = []
    labels = []

    rows = open(csvPath).read().strip().split("\n")[1:]
    random.shuffle(rows)

    for (i, row) in enumerate(rows):
        if i > 0:
            print("[INFO] processed {} total images".format(i))

        (label, imagePath) = row.strip().split(",")[-2:]

        imagePath = os.path.sep.join([basePath, imagePath])
        image = io.imread(imagePath)

        image = transform.resize(image, (224, 224))
        image = exposure.equalize_adapthist(image, clip_limit=0.1)

        data.append(image)
        labels.append(int(label))

    data = np.array(data)
    labels = np.array(labels)

    return (data, labels)

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input GTSRB")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to output model")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to training history plot")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

NUM_EPOCHS = 30
INIT_LR = 1e-4
BS = 64

labelNames = open("signnames.csv").read().strip().split("\n")[1:]
labelNames = [l.split(",")[1] for l in labelNames]

trainPath = os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"], "Train.csv"])
testPath = os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"], "Test.csv"])

print("[INFO] loading training and testing data...")
(trainX, trainY) = load_split(args["dataset"], trainPath)
(testX, testY) = load_split(args["dataset"], testPath)

trainX = (trainX-np.mean(trainX))/np.std(trainX)
testX = (testX-np.mean(testX))/np.std(testX)

numLabels = len(np.unique(trainY))
trainY = to_categorical(trainY, numLabels)
testY = to_categorical(testY, numLabels)

classTotals = trainY.sum(axis=0)
classWeight = classTotals.max() / classTotals

aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=10,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=False,
    vertical_flip=False,
    fill_mode="nearest")

print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR)
model = TrafficSignNet.build(width=224, height=224, depth=3,
    classes=numLabels)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

print("[INFO] training network...")
H = model.fit_generator(
    aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    steps_per_epoch=trainX.shape[0] // BS,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    class_weight=classWeight,
    verbose=1)

print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predictions = model.predict(testX, batch_size=BS)
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1),
    predictions.argmax(axis=1), target_names=labelNames))

print("[INFO] serializing network to '{}'...".format(args["model"]))
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

## Enddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Comment: Please include your code and error here.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGI8u.jpg

Comment: I want you to include your code, not a link to your code.

Comment: i include it ssss

Comment: @erip hey where are you bro help me

Answer (score 0):

I could not get access to your training script for some reason - can check your screenshot only.

I think your problem is not overfitting - your model is actually not learning, since the loss is not reduced while the accuracy keeps at the same level. Please double check you network, learning rate (most important) and preprocessing. Also, you may consider loading the VGG16 pretrained weight or not to load if you have done.

Or just post your code, I can take a look when I get a chance.

Update:

Based on your codes, I found you did not make any changes internally on the VGG16 - which is easy to debug.

1. Check you training and test set and make sure the classes are evenly distributed
2. Print out the label (Y test and train), carefully check if they are correct.
3. Try to standardize the X train and test instead of dividing by 255. x=(x-mean)/std
4. Try use learning rate as 0.0001 (I found it's generally good for VGG16 based network)
5. Stay simple at the first time. Don't use the decayed optimization, just try the standard ADAM firstly

Bests,

Comment: i post it pssssss

Comment: I added my suggestions based on your code. Hopeful can help you a little bit @SamiBen

Comment: hi @guoyili i changed the code according to the modifications that you told me, but the same problem remained, see the results

I have updated the post

Comment: Few further comments on your results: 1) try to relabel you data  with 0 and 1; 2) you dataset is probably too small to build a model to interpret your problem in this case - can you try to load the vgg16 pre-trained weight such as ImageNet?; 3) if you would like to check the training easily, you may want to plot the acc and loss separately. @SamiBen